How to add accessibility and keyboard navigation in Angular Plotly treemap?
We are using the angular plotly library to render treemap.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-plotly.js?activeTab=readme
The chart is not accessible and keyboard accessibility is also not there out of the box. How to make this accessible?
I contacted the Plotly team but they do not plan to add accessibility shortly.
I was looking for a solution.
This is the template part.
<plotly-plot [data]="[graph.data]" [layout]="graph.layout" (afterPlot)="heatmapLoaded()"></plotly-plot>

The ts part of the angular code is:
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'plotly-treemap-a11y';
    public graph = {
        data: {
            type: "treemap",
            labels: ["Root", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
            parents: ["", "Root", "Root", "A", "A", "B", "B"],
            values: [10, 20, 30, 15, 5, 10, 5],
            textinfo: "label+value",
            marker: {
                colors: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7],
                colorscale: "Viridis"
            }
        },
        layout: {
            title: "Sample Plotly Treemap",
            height: 500,
            width: 800
        }
    };
  }


It will draw the treemap like below.


Plotly.js? And what functions do you need to make accessible? I've done something similar myself but with their bar/pie charts, so I may be able to help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

We faced a similar issue in one of our projects. So I decided to create a package on top of plotly.
I created a small package that adds accessibility and keyboard navigation to the Angular Plotly treemap.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly-a11y-enhancer
The working demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1vvg9f?file=src%2Fmain.ts
